# setValue doesn't work in Google Apps

Tags: google-apps-script, setvalue

I have the following code:

```
var ee = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();

if (ee == "Stuff") {

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').setValue(emailAddress);

}

else {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Stuff").getRange('B2').setValue(emailAddress);

  }

}
```

When my activesheet is "MAIN", the 'else' is executed and the value of 'emailaddress' goes into cell B2 on the "Stuff" sheet.  BUT when my active sheet is "Stuff", even though the debugger shows that the first line is executed, NOTHING goes into B2!

Thanks.

Comment: What language or platform is this for? Please add some tags to it.

Comment: I think it's Google Apps Script, based on [this result](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp).

Comment: Tagged it, it is apps script.

Comment: Kinda curious, doesn't this code break the law of demeter?

Comment: @user2153057 why do you made the if on the first place. You can strip the if and leave only the code inside the _else_ clause, and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just always execute this?

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Stuff").getRange('B2').setValue(emailAddress);
```

You don't need the "if" because you do not have 2 different behaviors there. You're doing the same action in both parts. You're writing to the sheet called "Stuff".